# Why are there so few words in English that are derived from Welsh?

Tags: loanwords

Why are there so few words in English that are derived from Welsh?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Welsh_origin) mentions only 11.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Language origin specialists theorize that the proportion of loanwords in a language is a function of both the length of exposure to and the social status of the borrowed language.

English words borrowed from Celt are less than one hundred and probably more around 60.

However, the exposure of English to Welsh is long (449 AD to present) but the Welsh language had a lower status from the Saxon point of view.

Remember the double meaning of Wilisc in OE, the Saxon word for Celt (=> Welsh): it means both "foreigner" and "slave" (see the forms *Wyel*: slave, servant or Wylen: female slave).

Comment: Having the same word for foreigner and slave gives a pretty picture of a society :D

Comment: There's so much to say here. For instance, Ciao in Italian means "I'm you slave" (Sono il suo schiavo).  "Schiavone" in Italian means both Slav and slave.  Coming from Latin "sclavus" meaning both slave and Slav (=> Slovenia).  More food for thought is the etymology of "to bless" (=> Blood) and the fact that in many languages a "victim" is the same world for a victim of an sacrifice and of an accident ("Das Opfer" in German, "Victim" in many Latin languages).  Hard times...

Comment: @AlainPannetierΦ Actually, when an Italian tells you _ciao_ is to tell you _hello_, or _bye_; in no case, an Italian is telling you _I am your slave_. _Schiavone_ is a last name, and it is not used to mean an inhabitant of Croatia. That could be the etymology of the words, but it's not the actual meaning.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, May be I should have phrased it like this: "The [etymology of the Italian greeting *ciao* is "schiavo" which means "slave"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ciao&searchmode=none) as in "I'm you're servant".  I stand corrected for "Schiavone" being a last name only. Overall, the idea I meant to convey was that [slave comes from "Slav"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=slave&allowed_in_frame=0) as an example of the fact that there are many examples of substrate population names yieding words for *slave* in the conquering superstrate languages.

Answer (score 7):

The existing Celtic/Gaelic languages on the British Isles are considerably older than (Modern) English is.

They are native languages to the region. However, when England was first (and repeatedly) conquered (by the Saxons, the Nordic and the Normans), The Celtic regions were avoided and some of the midland natives fled to the extremities (Wales, Scotland, Ireland) and these areas remained largely untroubled by invasion.

There was a time when the districts of England were quite separate and there were many different native languages present (i.e. Manx, Cumbric, Cornish, Salopian). As the different occupations of England came and went, the language united and altered around them. Many of the original languages are now considered extinct.

Going back, you will find periods where the majority of English citizens spoke French and others where they spoke German (an old version of, at least), etcetera; Over time these languages all formed as one.

During these many transformations, the Gaelic and Celtic regions continued rather independently and their distinct languages are a mark of this. It is only in relatively recent times that any real interaction between those and English has occurred and as they have interacted, English has dominated, with the number Gaelic speakers in decline as English language takes over.

(Interestingly though, the Welsh are probably the most zealous in keeping their original languages alive, when compared with the others.)

Therefore, you will see that English, though one of the most widespread languages in the world, is really just a mixed bag of Latin, French, German Greek and old Norse but it is something quite separate from Welsh, Irish and Scottish as those nations were not involved in its political history.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @KarlMillsom, please not that the Celts are also invaders.  The craddle of the Celtic culture is located in Switzerland and Austria (Hallstatt culture).

Comment: Yes, you are quite right. They never really 'invaded' though, in the sense. They more trickled in (though, that they did so quite violently, I will not dispute). They were not at the time a unified people. You are right that they were not indigenous to the British Isles. However, the languages were well established by several hundred years (and separate from other local languages) by the time of Roman invasion

Comment: The anglo-saxons also trickled in according to one theory. It was more a case of a few well paid mercenaries with their flashy foreign ways that impressed the local girls - rather than a wave of 100,000 storming ashore and taking over

Comment: Bits of Yorkshire are an interesting case of this - it (almost) speaks English now, but with a lot more anglo-saxon. Most of the place names are Viking but the sheep farming is in ancient celtic - you count sheep in Yan Tan Tethera, and the hills are called things like pen-y-ghent.

Comment: Well yes, in fact under that theory one would even say that the Anglo-Saxons were invited. However, they later revolted/mutinied after not being paid their tribute or some other such grievance. The Anglo-Saxon 'invasion' was a fight to defeat the ruling classes and take control. The Celts were a number of rather unconnected tribes moving into a land already occupied by a number of rather unconnected tribes in more of an 'every man for himself' kind of way, just taking land as they went.

Comment: Also, you're quite right about Yorkshire. Cornwall is the same and even in the midlands where I come from, overhangs can be found of ancient languages. In fact Manx, which had died out completed, has now been revived and I think something like 1000 people can speak it again.

Comment: @Karl - I think it's still an active bit of language research, how come so few saxons managed to have such a complete effect on the language when a much more invasive invasion of Normans had so little.

Comment: @mgb: I think it is rather that the Saxons pushed the Celts away; the Saxons didn't impose their language on anyone, they just removed the Celtic speakers, whereas when the Normans came, becoming the aristocracy, the existing Saxon populace found it expedient to learn some French words.

Comment: @Mitch I think the current opinion is that the Saxon invasion was more a technology+culture+fashion thing. There were very few saxon invaders and very little change in the native inhabitants - but they all decided to 'become saxon' in dress, language, rituals etc. This comes from DNA, lack of change in farming practices etc. These guys were obviously very good at marketing!

Comment: I didn't know about the more recent stuff. All I know is that Old English, before the Norman invasion, and the ruling class were German without the name. So you're right,  their marketing department must be really good.

Comment: I don't believe that the majority of people in England ever spoke French as a first language. The ruling class did (so if you only count the rulers as citizens, maybe you're technically correct). The rest of the population spoke English among themselves, and probably most of them could speak bad French so as to communicate with the rulers.

Comment: Gaelic languages are Celtic. Manx is the language of the Isle of Man which is not part of England or the UK.

Comment: The "Celtic regions" (Celtic nations) also includes Cornwall with its distinct, Celtic history and language.

Comment: @Tristan: Manx is also a Celtic language. And since it's not part of England or Ireland, I think its location certainly means it counts as one of the British Isles.

Comment: Peter, yes. British Isles is a geographic term rather than a political one. Manx is one of the Gaelic/Goidelic group of Celtic languages.

Answer (score 1):

Wales didn't conquer/settle England (well sort of by proxy with Henry Tudor)

There wasn't a great deal of trade or much contact compared to with other countries.

It's art and culture has been a bit more'for consumption on the premises' than Ireland's export of writers and poets.

.... and of course because nobody else can understand or pronounce a word of it ....

Comment: Greece didn't conquer Rome. Take a look at the Byzantine culture

Comment: Most of common English loan words come from Norse, Anglo-saxon or Norman. There are a few more modern ones taken directly from Latin or Greece, but like those taken from Japanese they aren't as common

Answer (score 0):

Probably because Welsh is a modern language which was refreshed/reinvented (depending on your cultural view) during the 19th century, and so had no opportunity to affect any other language.  If you meant 'the Brythonic language spoken before the Roman conquest', that's a good question; but that had no more in common with modern Welsh than the language of the Viking Hrolf of Normandy had in common with modern French.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Welsh was continuously spoken as a language from before the Roman conquest to the modern day, as is evidenced by literary sources, in exactly the same way that the language spoken in Jutland evolved over the last 2500 years to become modern Danish. The proportion of speakers has decreased massively over time, but I'm not sure I see how anything that could be described as a refresh or a reinvention of _the language_. Welsh traditions, absolutely; the language, no.

Comment: Are you thinking of Cornish?

Comment: TimLymington
false. brythonic is very similar to welsh. people of Brittany who still speak it, can quite easily carry a conversation with welsh speakers. I can myself.
collect your facts before making such claims.

Comment: Cornish is also a Brythonic language.

Comment: @tony: does 'check your facts' include actually reading the post? "The Brythonic language spoken before the Roman conquest" does not mean *the modern languages that are usually termed brythonic*.

Comment: If Welsh was completely reinvented in the 19th century, why can the Bretons (who settled in France in the early middle ages) understand Welsh?

Comment: @Peter: because it was explicitly rebuilt/refurbished on Celtic lines, just as Irish was in the 1920s. In both cases there were many native speakers who were told their vocabulary and grammar were now 'wrong', which I consider relevant to the point OP actually asked. Once a language (as defined in the official textbooks) is taught in schools, I agree it soon becomes the official version. But that proves nothing either way about how it is connected to any previously used language.

Answer (score 0):

Not only are there few words of Celtic origin in English, but there are precious few place names in England of Celtic origin. This makes no sense when examining how cultures and languages spread throughout the world. For instance, in America there are thousands of place names derived from Native American languages in almost every state. About half of the states in the US have Indian names (Arizona, Alabama, Connecticut, Dakotas, Minnesota, Massachusetts...) in spite of the fact that these were a subjugated, technologically and numerically inferior peoples. This has been taken by some to suggest that some of the original inhabitants of England were not Celtic but Germanic (e.g. the Belgae — although they are reputed to be either Celtic or Germanic).  Makes sense to me.  If that were so, it would suggest that the Welsh and Picts and Caledonians were isolated from the English population even further back in time than in Caesar's day and might explain why when the Jutes and Saxons invaded they melded their languages with the primarily Germanic speaking inhabitants.  This is supported by modern-day genetic analyses.

This theory, which I am really just cribbing, is discussed by Stephen Oppenheimer in his book "The Origins of the British".

Answer (score -1):

The reason is very likely, despite the plethora of modern day books which describe the original inhabitants of Britain as "celtic", there is no compelling evidence that Celts were ever the original inhabitants of Britain.   Indeed, as Dr. Stephen Oppenheimer shows, there was NO suggestion at the time of the Roman invasion that the area that is today England was celtic.   Only a few loanwords today exist derived from Celtic and almost no placenames exist in modern day England that are Celtic in Origin.   Even Caesar described two different societies inhabiting England, one speaking Celtic on the western border of England and another society inhabiting what is modern day England which he described as speaking an entirely different language.   The Anglo-Saxon myth is pretty much debunked too, as it is more likely that the language spoken in England before Rome "invaded" was ancient, possibly much older than Celtic, and was already a germanic or more succinctly a scandinavian language.

Comment: *...and almost no placenames exist in modern day England that are Celtic...* This is nonsense. No one can seriously dispute that the ancestors of the modern Welsh people once inhabited a large part of what is now England. [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combe) list towns and villages which have 'combe' in their name. Combe comes from the same root as the Welsh word 'cwm' meaning valley. The river avon is literally the Welsh for river (afon). There are many other examples of Brythonic roots of English place names.

Answer (score -1):

A form of English was spoken by the Southern British before the Romans arrived, a form of Belgic German, it is more than likely that the Celts and English arrived in the British isles at the same time.

The English did not allow the Celts to settle, this is probably the reason there are hardly any Celtic place names in England.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: Also. it would be helpful if you could clarify how Celtic pertains specifically to Welsh language words.

Comment: We already know that the Suessiones were living in Britain at least 2 centuries before the Romans arrived, their gold coins were found from Kent to the Wash.