# Is "New and Improved" an oxymoron?

Tags: meaning, figures-of-speech, slogan

It irritates me that advertisers often claim a product is "New and Improved".  Surely, if something is **new** (ie, has not existed previously), it can't be **improved**!  And vice versa!

Comment: Rant disguised as a question? http://english.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Sounds better than "New but Crappier", doesn't it?

Comment: @PSU, yes, but that would most likely be more accurate :)

Comment: New does not mean there was not an old one.

Comment: @Jonathan Day, do you *honestly* believe that this is an oxymoron? Are you *actually* confused when confronted with this phrase? If not, then this is either a rant-disguised-as-question, or just being intentionally dense, trying to break this down with logic.

Comment: @Callithumpian and @tenfour - My question is genuine.  Apologies for sounding like a rant, but I wanted to validate whether my annoyance is valid.  My understanding of "new" is that of something that has not previously existed. However, As @Kosmonaut's answer illustrates, it is reasonable for "new" to also mean "different or better", hence the phrase in question is probably more tuatological than oxymoronic.  I'd appreciate it if your comments were a little less ... aggressive ... in future; suggesting that I'm being intentionally dense is a little flame-like...

Comment: While sometimes annoying you could always consider it to mean "new recipe and improved product". After all it's rarely stated *what's* new or improved. If you're feeling cynical how about "new recipe and improved profits"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no rule that says advertising language must adhere to perfect logic; however, in this case you are simply being too restrictive in your definition of *new*.

[Definitions 7-11 of *new*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/new):

> - coming or occurring afresh; further; additional: *new gains*.
> - fresh or unused: *to start a new sheet of paper*.
> - (of physical or moral qualities) different and better: *The vacation made a new man of him*.
> - other than the former or the old: *a new era*; *in the New world*.
> - being the later or latest of two or more things of the same kind: *the new testament*; *a new edition of Shakespeare*.

Among these definitions of *new*, there certainly seems to be a notion of something that is the next iteration, or a refurbished/remade product.  So, "new and improved" could be argued to be redundant, but not an oxymoron (unless you intentionally ignore some meanings of *new*).

Comment: It's true that advertising doesn't have to be logic. Using false logic is actually very common in advertising, like implying that something is best because "no other is better", or implying that a product is good because an absurd alternative is bad. :)

Answer (score 10):

[image: weasel words]

(Image comes from: http://xkcd.com/870/)

Answer (score 10):

It's advertising-speak, and that means it doesn't have to mean anything literally. (When an ad announces that something is "Free!" does anyone think you don't have to pay money to get it? Dream on!) Basically, some kind of research has determined that using "New! Improved!" (and, especially, "Free!") in an ad headline, copy, or voice-over leads to some percentage of increase in sales. It's about creating an impression.

That said, something can be *new* without being *improved*. And something can be *improved* without being *new*. A thing can also be both *new* and *improved*: it can be argued that Windows 7, say, was, when it was released, both a new version of Windows and an improvement over the old version (Vista). It was still, for all intents and purposes, a new version of Windows and an improved version of Windows. Vista was a new version of Windows that many people felt was not an improvement over Windows XP. New, but not improved. Therefore, the claim "new and improved" is neither a tautology nor an oxymoron.

I wouldn't worry too much about how accurate or honest or grammatical or self-consistent advertising copy is or should be. Most people hold it to a much lower standard than most of the rest of English.

Comment: ...but what wouldn't be an improvement over *Vista*?

Comment: Windows ME for one thing.

Answer (score 5):

On the contrary, it is more like a *tautology*.

That means that both words state the same and therefore one is redundant.

While the two words do carry slightly different meanings, they both convey the same general idea:

**new** as compared to old. *Here is the new one and there is the old one.* ~Shows that this has replaced the older version.

**improved** and thus better than the old one. *The old version was unreliable, this new version is much improved.* ~Shows that it has been remodeled or somehow made better.

Therefore, we could take away either word and essentially have the same concept.

The better word to keep would be **improved** since 'new' can be incorporated in its meaning', while something being new doesn't incorporate 'improvement' (consider new versions of your favourite childhood cartoons/TV shows!)

Hope this helps.

N.B.: It might be important to note that the word **improved** can be used for repairing items (like a damaged bicycle), in which case the item in question would not be new.

However, in the context of this question that sense is not relevant, since your broken and then fixed bicycle would not likely be the subject of an advertising campaign to sell it back to you.

Comment: To add to this answer, the phrase, "In with the new, same as the old" has meaning and is relatively understandable.

Comment: Improved does not always incorporate new. You can improve existing things (like fix a bicycle), without it being considered new in the accepted sense.

Comment: Yes, I considered that shortly after posting @apoorv. I still think 'improved' is better than 'new', and that it *often* incorporates new, so have been trying to think of a reword that will say that.

Comment: Something can be both new and improved. They have different meanings which can be meaningful independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

I usually take it to mean that it's a new version of something already in existence and it's improved (as in better than the one before, not worse). That way, it makes sense to me so it's not an oxymoron.

Answer (score 1):

The most typical examples of [oxymorons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron) are phrases in which the meaning of an adjective contradicts the very nature of the noun with which it is associated.

A well know example is a "deafening silence" or its symmetric a "silent scream".

In the example you cite, we have two adjectives and they don't have opposite meanings.

You possibly meant a [pleonasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) - a commonly observed phenomenon in advertising slogans [1].  Yet "New and Improved" would not qualify either since, as many have already pointed out, newer things are not necessarily marked improvements on older ones.

[1] Celtic (Gaelic) etymology. [Hear, hear](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19328/why-are-there-so-few-words-in-english-that-are-derived-from-welsh).

Answer (score 1):

Literally, possibly, but I classify it almost as [an idiomatic expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiomatic_expression) and, like (nearly) all idioms, mean something different than the literal meaning of their compotent terms.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that calling something *new* does not make it so. Windows versions don't need to be considered new but just improved over the last one no matter the numbering. Windows was an improvement over DOS but certainly not a new version of DOS. *New and improved* is at best old and impoverished jargon of the advertising world, not proper English. A several-page scan of a Google search gives only marketing-related firms using this phrase in their own names.

Answer (score -1):

If "new" is understood in its strictest sense, and if "improved" is understood in its strictest sense, then "new and improved" is a contradiction.  It is not an oxymoron in the strictest sense, however.  An oxymoron is by definition a two-word contradiction.

Answer (score -5):

What are you kidding me? New and Improved are two different words with two different meanings. Something can be new and can be a disaster.  you've read your cereal box so much that you think the two words are synonyms.  watch out for hucksters like most companies pushing new and improved.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question. The question asks about the logic of calling something improved if it is new. i.e. if it didn't exist before, how can it be an improvement?